# the best way or different ways to call a function in powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am looking for the best way to call a function in powershell.

I search on google and find the two below ways to call a function. Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1

1. func -Size 50 -Length 100
2. func 50 100

Note - Assume function with name 'func' and 2 params ($Size, $Length)

is there any different way other than mentioned above to call a function in PowerShell ?

Comment: Both ways are valid, there is no "better way" except for _named parameters_ being more verbose could help others get a better understanding of what your function is doing.

Comment: Let's put it other way: if you call `myFunction foo bar true`, what on earth does it do? Consider then `myFunction -computername foo -powerprofile bar -force true`; now you already have a quite good idea that it's going to force a power profile to a computer.

Comment: you should presume that what CAN go wrong WILL [eventually] go wrong. [*grin*] so the _safe_ way to call a function or a cmdlet is with the fully spelled out parameter names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by [**@Santiago**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon):

> Both ways are valid, there is no "better way" except for named parameters being more verbose could help others get a better understanding of what your function is doing

The *best practice* (for this particular question) is actually included in [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) that comes standard with e.g. the [PowerShell Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and gives you (best practice) warnings on the fly.

You might also install `PSScriptAnalyzer` and check your scripts with [`Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psscriptanalyzer/invoke-scriptanalyzer).

The specific rule that applies to your question can be checked with [`Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psscriptanalyzer/get-scriptanalyzerrule):

```
(Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule PSAvoidUsingPositionalParameters).Description
```

> Readability and clarity should be the goal of any script we expect to maintain over time. When calling a command that takes parameters, where possible consider using name parameters as opposed to positional parameters. To fix a violation of this rule, please use named parameters instead of positional parameters when calling a command.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are valid, the first one is a beat clearer because of the variables names